# Create Windows 7 Library on custom location

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, windows-10, windows-8.1

I want to create a "virtual" folder or Windows 7 Library on a custom location, for example "C:\Program Files\SomeSoftware", and link to there folders that are on a different drive, so SomeSoftware can be cheated as is everything were installed on C:\ (SomeSoftware automatically installs on C and location can't be changed at any point). Apparently, the Windows Libraries have its own location which is not user accessible, or at least I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a symbolic link.

Open an administrative command prompt.

Type:

```
mklink /d C:\Program Files\SomeSoftware\FOLDERNAME D:\Path\To\Folder
```

This will create a folder within C:\Program Files\SomeSoftware\FOLDERNAME that actually points to a different location.

Comment: And how to I make it on a NTFS partition from Linux? Because a lot of DLL's on those folders are in use.

Comment: @Smeterlink From within Linux isn't possible apparently ([see here](http://serverfault.com/questions/165389/create-ntfs-symbolic-links-from-within-linux)). You may be able to boot into Safe Mode to make the necessary changes, although I'm not sure what software you're trying to use, I'd assume it wouldn't run in Safe Mode and therefore the DLLs for it wouldn't be in use?

Comment: I guess I can create some example link and edit it under linux with some hexadecimal editor to point to the new location after moving the folders.
Also, why don't you use /J instead of /D parameter?